# После авторизации не переходит на страницу личного кабинета

Tags: php

Всем доброй ночи! Столкнулся с проблемой, что при авторизации пользователя, не переходит на страницу личного кабинета, а просто будто обновляется login.php.

Ошибка:

```
Notice: Undefined index: pass in /var/www/fa063859/data/www/site.ru/cp/login.php on line 5
```

login.php:

```
<?php

require '../engine/function.php';
require '../engine/authorization.php';
if(!(empty($_COOKIE["pass"]) || $_COOKIE["pass"]=="")) return header("Location: ./");

 $template = 
     str_replace(array(
            '{%isclass%}'
        ),
        array(
        ),
        file_get_contents('../templates/header.tpl')) .
     str_replace(array(
            '{%isclass%}'
        ),
        array(
        ),
        file_get_contents('../templates/login.tpl')) . 
        str_replace(array(
            '{%footer%}',
        ),
        array(
        ),
        file_get_contents('../templates/footer.tpl'));

    exit($template);
?>
```

line 5:

```
if(!(empty($_COOKIE["pass"]) || $_COOKIE["pass"]=="")) return header("Location: ./");
```

authorization.php:

```
<?
require_once 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{   
    $name = $_POST['nick'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $search = mysqli_query($_MS, "SELECT * FROM `".$account['table']."` WHERE `".$account['name']."`='$name'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($search)!=0)
    {
        $user = mysqli_fetch_array($search);
        if($user[$account['pass']]==$password)
        {
            setcookie("pass", md5(md5($password)).":".$name, time() + 60*100, "/");
            header("Location: ./");
        }
        else
        {
            $info_pass="<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">
  <strong>Ошибка!</strong> Пароль не правильный.
</div>";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $info_user = "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">
  <strong>Ошибка!</strong> Игрок не найден.
</div>";
    }
}

if(isset($_GET["access"])=="exit") {
    setcookie("pass", "", "0", "/");
    header("Location: ./login.php");
}   
?>
```

**Что делать?**

Comment: Я бы для начала выкинул тот учебник, с которого списан весь этот ужас. И купил нормальный.

Comment: +1 за начать с книг. зы: проверка логина/пароль это аутентификация, а не авторизация